# specify upload destination with multiple LIBCLOUD_PROVIDERS settings

Tags: django, django-storage

I have to `fileField` I want to have a different cloud storage for each

How to specify the upload destination on the field settings level.

Doc link:
http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/apache_libcloud.html